# How to process DLQ messages during off-peak hours

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Our requests are currently rate limited by an external API so we want to develop a retry mechanism.

For this, we have decided to use SQS (to queue all requests), connected to a Lambda function (to call the external API). As per defaults 3 Lambda function retries look good but is there any way we can schedule those retries after X second (Since the external API returns back after how many seconds we can retry)?

And for requests which are failed even after 3 retries, we have decided to use DLQ (Dead Letter Queues) and to process those requests in off-peak hours. So what is the best way to do this? We are currently thinking to launch another consumer connected only to DLQ, triggered though Scheduled Events Cron.

Also what happens if the requests in DLQ are failed? We still want to process those.

Thanks

Comment: I've wondered about a similar scenario but not had to solve it yet. A possibility - if you're dealing with a lot of data - would be to use kinesis Streams for your failed requests and to smooth out your workload. I've not done it so can't recommend it. Otherwise retrying periodically from the DLQ was my idea too. It is now possible to trigger lambdas directly from SQS now too but that doesn't solve your smoothing problem.

Comment: @macbutch I have actually got a workaround. In case of failure, I can delete message from SQS then re add the same message with initial invisibility period equal to the retry time (got from external API). In this way I can build my own retry mechanism (both SQS and DLQ) according to my needs.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-message-timers.html

Comment: Thanks, @Saad, that seems like a really good approach actually. I think I can adapt that to my case if I ever have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually got a workaround. In case of failure, I can delete message from SQS then re add the same message with initial invisibility period equal to the retry time (got from external API). In this way I can build my own retry mechanism (both SQS and DLQ) according to my needs.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-message-timers.html